# Dynamically change the fields of reports in SSRS

Tags: inheritance, reporting-services, visual-studio-2019

I have around 10 reports in SSRS and I want to make look and feel same for all the reports. In order to do so I have created a report and save as **Template** and all the reports have been created using that template.

But problem now is that I cannot set height,widths,font ect. simultaneously for all the reports . I am making changes in all reports one by once which is time consuming.

**Now If I needed to change a header text or something, I could just alter the master report and that change would propagate to all inherited reports.**

Is this possible using Reporting Services, visual studio 2019.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that is not possible.

As a workaround:

Since rdl is xml files, you could open multiple reports with an editor(eg. notepad++), find the part you want to change in the xml code and use replace all functionallity.

Comment: As of now I have 10 reports, but tomorrow it could be 100+. In that case this workaround will be time consuming.I need to open each report and than change the font, height width etc. which will be lengthily.

Comment: Alternatives could be change rdl in the SSRS database using SQL or have a settings table and use its values inside the report configuration (not everything can be parameter based). Also check if report parts or embeded reports(subreports) cover some of the functionality you ask. Unfortunately there is no such thing as a template with inheritance.